# How to get album images from an image hosting website and automatically display it in a website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I have a multiple public photo images in an album hosted by a free website and I have a website with gallery. I want to get automatically all the photos uploaded in my album and have it displayed in my website gallery.  Is there a javascript for this? or any apps that could help me? My website is static, btw.

Answer (score 1):

You have several choices:

1. Create an iframe on your website and display the gallery from the free website in the iframe.
2. Find out if the public website has an API that would let you get a list of image URLs from your gallery.  If so, write client-side javascript to use that API to fetch the image URLs and then create a new gallery view on your website using those URLs.
3. Use a server to request the free web-site gallery and then "scrape" the image URLs from the returned HTML to generate a list of image URLs in that gallery.  Use an ajax call to fetch that list of images URLs from your server and then build the gallery on your site that you want.
4. Use the same server to scrape the image URLs and then use it to build the desired gallery HTML which you can request from your client.

Keep in mind that because of browser security and the same-origin-policy, you cannot use ajax from a browser to third party sites at a different domain than your web page comes from without a cooperating server that can do JSONP.

Comment: Can you list any fee website that has an API?

Comment: @winona - You might check on [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/).  It doesn't cost much for some pay sites with an API.  For example, [Smugmug's basic account](http://www.smugmug.com/photos/photo-sharing-features/) has API access for $40/yr with unlimited storage and bandwidth.  Depending upon what you're doing, you will have to check to see if it complies with the license restrictions for using the APIs.